# Android Gradle how to exclude buttonBarStyle from .aar dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android studio project that uses the android support library.  I'm not trying to include a .aar library.  When I do so, I get the following errors:

/Users/kyle/development/Android/UBT_Wallet/app/src/main/res/values/color.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "buttonBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(2) Attribute "buttonBarButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/kyle/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

How do I exclude the barButtonStyle and buttonBarButtonStyle styles from being included?

Comment: Where is the second `buttonBarButtonStyle` coming from? Your code?

Comment: The first buttonBarButtonStyle is defined in the appcompat-v7 library.  I am now trying to include another 3rd party library in the form of an .aar.  When I include the .aar, the error present.  I have unzipped the .aar and found that the library defines the style in a values.xml file.

Comment: did you find an answer